# Vue plugin working on nuxt server load but not on client navigation (vue-scrollactive)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a Nuxt application where I've installed [vue-scrollactive](https://github.com/eddiemf/vue-scrollactive) as a plugin.

I am using it on a child page (ie website.com/company). If I do a fresh load of website.com/company the plugin works fine - however, if I load the site from another page (ie website.com or website.com/about) using `nuxt-link` then the scrollactive plugin does not work.

UPDATE:
It appears to be something to do with the `fetchState` and the `main` tag appearing on `v-else`.  I tested with dummy data using `fetch` and it worked.

plugins/scrollActive.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import scrollactive from 'vue-scrollactive'
Vue.use(scrollactive)
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/scrollActive' }],
```

pages/company.vue

```html
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen bg-gray-100">
    <TheAppNavbar :company="company" />

    <!-- Subnav  -->
    <scrollactive
        :offset="30"
        :highlight-first-item="true"
        scroll-container-selector="#data-area"
        class="block h-16 overflow-x-auto border-b dark:border-gray-600 md:hidden bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800 scrollbars-hidden my-nav"
    >
        <div class="inline-flex items-center h-full text-lg">
            <a
                v-for="category in categories"
                :key="category"
                :href="`#${category}`"
                class="flex items-center h-full text-gray-500 capitalize scrollactive-item dark:text-gray-400'"
            >
                <span v-if="publicCat(category)" class="mx-4 sm:mx-8">{{
                    category
                }}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </scrollactive>

    <!-- Bottom section -->
    <div class="flex flex-1 min-h-0">
        <!-- Narrow sidebar-->
        <scrollactive
            :offset="30"
            :highlight-first-item="true"
            scroll-container-selector="#data-area"
            aria-label="Sidebar"
            class="hidden bg-gray-800 dark:bg-white w-28 md:flex md:flex-col md:overflow-y-auto scrollbars-hidden my-nav"
        >
            <div class="relative flex flex-col px-2 mt-4 space-y-2">
                <a
                    v-if="publicCat('sports')"
                    href="#sports"
                    class="flex scrollactive-item"
                >
                    <span class="mt-2">Sports</span>
                </a>
                <a
                    v-if="publicCat('finance')"
                    href="#finance"
                    class="flex scrollactive-item"
                >
                    <span class="mt-2">Finance</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </scrollactive>

        <!-- Main area -->
        <div v-if="$fetchState.pending">
             Loading
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
            An error occurred :(
        </div>
        <main 
            v-else
            id="data-area"
        >
            <section
                v-for="cat in categories"
                :id="cat"
                :key="cat"
                aria-labelledby="primary-heading"
                class="flex flex-col flex-1"
            >
                <div v-if="company[cat].public === true">
                    <div id="section-header">
                        <h2>
                            {{ cat }}
                        </h2>
                        <p v-if="formattedDate(cat) !== null">
                            Updated:
                            {{ formattedDate(cat) }}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <CompanySports
                        v-if="cat === 'sports'"
                        class="pb-20 sm:pt-8"
                        :financials="company.sports"
                    />

                    <CompanyFinance
                        v-if="cat === 'finance'"
                        class="pb-20 sm:pt-8"
                        :financials="company.finance"
                    />

                </div>
            </section>

            <a
                :href="`https://${company.website}`"
                target="_blank"
                >Visit Website
               </a>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

...

methods: {
    publicCat(cat) {
        if (this.company[cat]) {
            if (this.company[cat].public === true) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    },
    formattedDate(cat) {
        if (this.company[cat].updated) {
            const date = new Date(this.company[cat].updated.seconds * 1000)
            return date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
                year: 'numeric',
                month: 'short',
                day: 'numeric',
            })
        }

        return null
    },
},
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a github repo since it's looking fine at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hacky but I changed the main area without the `v-else` and added
`v-if="$fetchState.pending === false"` and `:class="company === {} ? 'hidden' : 'block'"` to a `div` that enclosed the area with data.  Works for now but not ideal.

```
<!-- Main area -->
    <div v-if="$fetchState.pending">
         Loading
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
        An error occurred :(
    </div>
    <main 
        id="data-area"
    >
        <section
            v-for="cat in categories"
            :id="cat"
            :key="cat"
            aria-labelledby="primary-heading"
            class="flex flex-col flex-1"
        >
            <div 
                v-if="$fetchState.pending === false && company[cat].public === true"
                :class="company === {} ? 'hidden' : 'block'"
            >
                <div id="section-header">
                    <h2>
                        {{ cat }}
                    </h2>
                    <p v-if="formattedDate(cat) !== null">
                        Updated:
                        {{ formattedDate(cat) }}
                    </p>
                </div>

                <CompanySports
                    v-if="cat === 'sports'"
                    class="pb-20 sm:pt-8"
                    :financials="company.sports"
                />

                <CompanyFinance
                    v-if="cat === 'finance'"
                    class="pb-20 sm:pt-8"
                    :financials="company.finance"
                />

            </div>
        </section>

        <a
            v-if="$fetchState.pending === false"
            :class="company === {} ? 'hidden' : 'block'"
            :href="`https://${company.website}`"
            target="_blank"
            >Visit Website
           </a>
    </main>
```